# Ionic 4 tabs routing not change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4, angular-router

i ionic 4 tabs using. Hardware back button listener on the OtherTabPage. HomeTabPage and OtherTabPage icons remain selected when the hardwareBackButton function runs. but there is no problem running onClick function.

[error-tabs-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ib72.jpg)

```
otherTabPage.html

<ion-button (click)="onClick()">
Go Home
</ion-button>
```

```
export class OtherTabPage {

constructor(private platform: Platform) {
        this.hardwareBackButton();
    }

hardwareBackButton() {
        this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
               this.router.navigateByUrl('/'); // Go to home
    });
}

 onClick() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/'); // Go to home
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the html?